# How do I begin a CAAnimation?

Tags: ios, scenekit, caanimation

I'm working in objective-c using scenekit and added a CABasicAnimation to my root node in viewdidLoad (also tried in viewdidAppear). It just spins the object around infinitely. I'm also using allowsCameraControl. I used

`[_sceneKitView.scene.rootNode addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"spin"];`

and it works but doesn't begin until after I pan to move the object.

This question seems so basic and I keep looking for something like:

```
[rootNode beginAnimationWithKey:@"spin]
```

but haven't been able to find it. How do I begin the CAAnimation as soon as the scene loads?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to rotate the scene's root node. That doesn't seem right as any other object's transform is relative to the root node. Your camera is somewhere under the root node and so you won't see anything happen.

Comment: mnuages makes a good point. I rearranged things so that the animation was applied only to the node containing the object to be rotated and it magically starts the animation upon loading. Still can't figure out why it worked before after use of camera control, but this did fix my problem. Only difference is now the lights stay fixed whereas before they rotated with the object. I can't decide which looks better so this will work for now.